# Laravel saving multiple relationships in one go

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

In my laravel application I have two models that have a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Organisation extends Eloquent {

    public function projects() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
    }

}

class Project extends Eloquent {
    public function organisations() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Organisation');
    }
}
```

What is the best way I can save multiple relationships in one go. For example an organisations is related to 4 projects, how I represent that in eloquent?

I thought I would be something like this,

```
   $projects = array(4561, 9874, 7762); //array of project IDs
   if($organisation->save()) {
       $organisation->projects()->sync($projects);
    }
```

However this does not seem to save the relationship, but I get no error messages either.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to link m-m relationship. How can you tell this is not working?

Comment: This will work and i have been using this in all my project . can you share more details